# Making a stone sieve out of wood

Tags: design

I would love to make a stone sieve out of wood. The best thing I can think of is to take a piece of wood and drill lots of holes in it. And I would be putting siding on of coarse. What size holes should I use? What could I do to prevent clogging of the soil if any? And maybe somebody has a blue print or a different and better way of making something like this.

Comment: What is a "stone picker" ?  I sounds like you are asking about something like a  garden sieve or competition screen, to separate rocks out of soil; if so , a metal screen or grid will work better than a wooden one...

Comment: Compost, not competition. Grumble touchscreen...

Comment: Based on the answers given, I would use the term "sieve", not "stone picker".

Answer (score 5):

Here's one I made a few years ago from scraps. I believe this is what you're trying to make.

[image: Garden Sieve]

It's 2x4" for the main walls, with a 1/4" mesh grill acting as the actual sieve. The mesh is stapled to the 2x4's, and has a 1x2" furring piece underneath so that you don't catch your fingers on the metal.

The size of mine is 36" x 26" - I built it specifically to fit over the top of my big wheelbarrow. The sifted soil goes into the wheelbarrow, and the rocks and weeds get tipped into another wheelbarrow next to it.

Not pretty, but functional. Just like me!

Comment: My wife made one very similar to this for working in the garden.

Answer (score 2):

> What size holes should I use?

Surely this is going to depend on the size of the stones *you* need to exclude? I imagine any soil is going to contain a wide range of pebble sizes, how large the ones you need to screen out is entirely up to what you need to get out of it.

> What could I do to prevent clogging of the soil if any?

I'm not sure if this is an issue that can be addressed in the abstract, it will depend on variables that haven't been established: the type of soil you have (sandy or clay-ey or middling) if obviously the first thought, but of course the size(s) of the holes drilled in the wood will be a factor and you haven't decided on that yet.

> And maybe somebody has a blue print or a different and better way of making something like this.

I believe these are usually made from a metal screen tacked to a wooden frame, and I would think there's a reason that's the most common format!

A metal screen is going to be much more robust and hard-wearing than perforated wood and it would more easily withstand getting hosed off at the end of a session. Wood *can* deal with getting wet and then drying out repeatedly of course, but there are usually some consequences (splinters, cracks forming etc.) which may too quickly affect function.